# webpack definePlugin failed

Tags: webpack, vue.js, gulp

I tried using Webpack to set environment variables for my Vue project,  but `DefinePlugin` does not work, it keeps on giving me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined`. Here's the webpack.config.js.

```
import webpack from 'webpack'; 

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './app'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {loader: 'html-loader'}
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV' : JSON.stringify('production')
        })
    ]
};
```

and the error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined
at DefinePlugin.apply (/Users/david/Documents/black-tux-cms/node_modules/webpack/lib/DefinePlugin.js:42:18)
at Compiler.apply (/Users/david/Documents/black-tux-cms/node_modules/webpack-stream/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:375:16)
at webpack (/Users/david/Documents/black-tux-cms/node_modules/webpack-stream/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:33:19)
at Stream.<anonymous> (/Users/david/Documents/black-tux-cms/node_modules/webpack-stream/index.js:134:20)
at _end (/Users/david/Documents/black-tux-cms/node_modules/through/index.js:65:9)
at Stream.stream.end (/Users/david/Documents/black-tux-cms/node_modules/through/index.js:74:5)
at module.exports (/Users/david/Documents/black-tux-cms/node_modules/webpack-stream/index.js:214:12)
at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/david/Documents/black-tux-cms/gulp/tasks/scripts.js:8:15)
at module.exports (/Users/david/Documents/black-tux-cms/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/david/Documents/black-tux-cms/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
```

I'm using gulp to compile all my source files. I am new in gulp, webpack and vue.

Comment: what webpack version do you use? post your package.json

Comment: You might try `const webpack = require('webpack');` instead of the `import`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version of **webpack** you are using , your configurations might vary , try

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin(
{ 
    PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(true) 
}
);
```

instead

and lets see the results , Have you also tried [any other plugins](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/) instead ... perhaps the **IgnorePlugin** , like this

`new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)`

Does it compile without errors? It's probably you are mixing up the versions :D

Answer (score 0):

also depending on your environment, replace 'import webpack ... with

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
```